# How to convert from List<object> to List<T> in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a Class:

```
public class Element
{
   public List<object> objects { get; set; }
}
```

And a Class:

```
public class Node
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
    }
```

I pass in a `List<object> nodes`. So is there any way I can convert those `List<object> objects`  to `List<Node> nodes`?

I tried this way but it doesn't work
`List<Node> nodes = objects.Select(s => (nodes)s).ToList();`

Comment: (nodes)  - this is unknown type.

`List<Node> nodes = objects.Select(s => (Node)s).ToList();`

Comment: Are the elements in the `objects` list actually a `Node` type? How does the code you've tried not work, besides you casting to `nodes` instead of `Node`?

Comment: maybe `var result = objects.Cast<Node>();`

Comment: Here is the list passed in. I get them from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ```{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 1000828751,
  "nodes": [
    9238280575,
    9238280590,
    9238280589,
    9238280576,
    9238280592,
    9238280577,
    9238280578,
    9238280575
  ],
  "tags": {
    "amenity": "fire_station",
    "name": "Đội Cảnh sát PCCC & CNCH quận Long Biên"
  }
}```

Comment: that json doesn't not equal your model. Your data is literally `int[]`.

Comment: I use ```HttpClient``` to get the list and convert it to a class containing ``List<Element>``. But ```list node``` in the return result only gets ``List<Object> nodes``.

Comment: "I tried this way but it doesn't work" - Always include error messages for things that "does not work". You should also include the code that produced the list in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is this:

```
{  "type": "way",
  "id": 1000828751,
  "nodes": [
    9238280575,
    9238280590,
    9238280589,
    9238280576,
    9238280592,
    9238280577,
    9238280578,
    9238280575
  ],
  "tags": {
    "amenity": "fire_station",
    "name": "Đội Cảnh sát PCCC & CNCH quận Long Biên"
  }
}
```

When I use https://json2csharp.com to create the C# classes I get this:

```
public class Root
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<object> nodes { get; set; }
    public Tags tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tags
{
    public string amenity { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And that does successfully deserialize your JSON, but that's where you're at, trying to convert `List<object>` to `List<long>`. However, the tool could have done better had it defined `nodes` like this:

```
public class Root
{
    ...
    public List<long> nodes { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

That now works without any further code changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
where listObject is the `List<object>`

```
List<Node> newlist = listObject.Cast<Node>().ToList();
```

Comment: This code does not work. When the underlying type is `List<long>` you cannot cast to `Node`.